# Is there a way to use solver.unsat_core, without using solver.assert_and_track?

Tags: python, logic, z3, smt, z3py

Is there any way to make the following code work, and print out a valid unsat core?

```
from z3 import *

a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')

s = Solver()
s.add(a == 1)
s.add(a == 2)
s.add(b == 3)

s.check()

# This prints [], and I would like it to print [a == 1, a == 2]
print(s.unsat_core())
```

I know I could do this instead:

```
from z3 import *

a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')

s = Solver()
s.assert_and_track(a == 1, 'p1')
s.assert_and_track(a == 2, 'p2')
s.assert_and_track(b == 3, 'p3')

s.check()
# This prints [p1, p2]
print(s.unsat_core())
```

But for the real project I'm working on, it would be painful to go through and give names to every constraint (due to their volume, as well as how they're generated.)

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you implement it yourself. Unsat core extraction requires labeling the constraints, see top of page 67 of this document: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf

Having said that, you can build a "database" of your assertions by defining your own version of `add` that first makes up a name and inserts it, and then do the reverse lookup in a function `my_unsat_core` that you would similarly define. If you were to implement this in a generic way, Z3 folks might be interested in incorporating it into their API as well. Would be a nice addition.

Comment: What I ended up doing was similar to what you suggest. I implemented my own version of add, that used `assert_and_track` under the hood (using: .assert_and_track(expr, str(expr)))

Comment: Nice.. If you can, please add it to a repo and share with the rest of us. Or better yet, send the Z3 guys a pull request at their github site: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3